# Creating Lists with Similar Dates from Pandas Column

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

I have a Pandas Data Frame containing date and category. For same dates there might be more than 1 category. Example df:

```
+------------+----------+
|    Date    | Category |
+------------+----------+
| 2020-01-02 | A        |
| 2020-01-02 | B        |
| 2020-01-02 | C        |
| 2020-01-02 | D        |
| 2020-02-20 | E        |
| 2020-02-20 | F        |
| 2020-02-20 | G        |
+------------+----------+
```

I want to create a function to give an output list one for date and other for Category.

**Desired Output:**

```
date_list = [['2020-01-02'], ['2020-02-20']]
category_list = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D',], ['E','F','G']]
```

Note that there can more than 2 distinct dates and the output would then change accordingly.

The purpose to get such an output is that I've to pass lists to an API that would give me prices against
each category. I can create a list simply by

```
date_list = df.Date.tolist()
```

and

```
category_list = df.Category.tolist()
```

Passing such list would make multiple calls to the API and would take long. If there are similar categories on same date then I would pass a list of single date and list of categories on that date. It would look something like

```
zipped = zip(category_list, date_list)
for i, j in zip:
    result = get_data(i, j)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create list per groups by [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
s = df.groupby('Date')['Category'].agg(list)
print (s)
Date
2020-01-02    [A, B, C, D]
2020-02-20       [E, F, G]
Name: Category, dtype: object

#for one element lists use lsit comprehension
date_list = [[x] for x in s.index]
category_list = s.tolist()

print (date_list)
[['2020-01-02'], ['2020-02-20']]
print (category_list)
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G']]
```

If need pass to function is possible loop by `Series s` by [`Series.items`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.items.html):

```
s = df.groupby('Date')['Category'].agg(list)

for i, j in s.items():
    print ([i], j)
['2020-01-02'] ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
['2020-02-20'] ['E', 'F', 'G']
```